# Higher education runs on me, A noun or a verb I can be, With my first letter gone, I’m a fit, on and on

Tags: riddle, word

> Higher education runs on me,
> A noun or a verb I can be,
> With my first letter gone,
> I’m a fit, on and on

This riddle has a five letter word lock and it is was grandpa and I want to open it.

Comment: What is a "five word lock" - do you mean a five letter word? What does "it is was grandpa" mean?

Comment: Oop sorry yes I meant 5 letter word

Comment: Hello @D2oubleJoker. Is the answer correct? If yes please accept it. If not please explain why not. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Is the word

> GRANT

Higher Education runs on

> Grants

It is a noun as well as a verb

With my 1st letter gone I am a fit, on and on

> Rant:  ranting goes on and on like you are having a fit